# Grid container like Bootstrap container

Tags: material-ui

So, I want to create a page layout what will look like this: [image]

For example, in Bootstrap I can simple write:

```
<div class="container">
  <!-- Content here -->
</div>
```

And everything will be cool.

Is there a good clean solution to do something like this in Material-UI? By default Grid system create fluid-container with full width.

Comment: Kind of solution coud be using Grid like that:
 <Grid container>
     <Grid item  lg= {3}>
     </Grid>
     <Grid item lg={6}>
     //your content
     </Grid>
     <Grid item  lg= {3}>
     </Grid>
</Grid>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be accomplished using the [Grid](https://material-ui-next.com/api/grid/) component and [Responsive Breakpoints](https://material-ui-next.com/layout/css-in-js/#responsive-breakpoints).  Take a look at the [Layout, Grid](https://material-ui-next.com/layout/grid/) page in the docs.

Here is an example:

```js
const styles = theme => ({
  demo: {
    height: 240,
    background: "#f00",
    [theme.breakpoints.up("lg")]: {
      width: 1170
    }
  }
});

class ResponsiveGrid extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <Grid container justify="center">
        <Grid
          container
          className={classes.demo}
          alignItems="center"
          justify="center"
        >
          <Grid lg={12} item>Content Here</Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(ResponsiveGrid);
```

We define a set of styles which are added to the component as the `classes` prop using [withStyles](https://material-ui-next.com/guides/typescript/#usage-of-withstyles).  The `demo` class uses the `theme` to create a media query for the theme's `lg` breakpoint.  For viewports `lg` or larger, width will be set to `1170`.

A large viewport is considered to be between 1280 and 1919 px.  These are the defaults and are based on the Material Design standard.

Read more about [Responsive Breakpoints](https://material-ui-next.com/layout/basics/#breakpoints) and see this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pp9mkmrnl0) for a working version of my example.

Comment: Thank you very much! This solution is really working. But the con of this method is that you need to create special class. I hope Material-UI developers will add native feature for this.

Comment: This is not really the same as bootstraps container. I would also love to see a bootstrap like container in material ui

Comment: @Jonas This answer meets OP's objective and is generic enough.  It uses the material-ui styling solution (at the time it was written).  At this point, you'd probably handle this better using their upcoming style system: https://material-ui.com/system/basics/#-material-ui-system

Answer (score 7):

I solved this problem by creating a custom CSS file and pasting in the bootstrap `.container` class from `bootstrap-grid.css` file like this.

custom-style.css

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 540px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 720px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 960px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1140px;
  }
}
```

and simply import this `custom-style.css` file into your `index.js` file of your ReactJS project.

```
import 'path/to/your/custom-style.css';
```

In material-ui, Predefined components have their own paddings setup and when combining them with our custom `.container` class, it might give additional un-wanting padding, to overcome this problem, we can write our helper classes in the same `custom-style.css` file like this.

```
// padding helper classes
.p-0 {
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.pt-0 {
  padding-top: 0 !important;
}

.pb-0 {
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.ptb-0 {
  padding-top: 0 !important;
  padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

after this is setup, we can use our custom classes just like we use it in html markup, but in React, with `className` property

```
<Grid container>
  <AppBar position="static">
    <div className="container">
      <Toolbar className="p-0" >
        <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" className={classes.grow}>
          Learning
        </Typography>
        <Hidden xsDown>
          <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
          <Button color="inherit">Register</Button>
        </Hidden>
        <Hidden smUp>
          <IconButton className={classes.menuButton} color="inherit" aria-label="Menu">
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </Hidden>
      </Toolbar>
    </div>
  </AppBar>
</Grid>
```

and now it is aligned properly just like bootstrap `.container` class

[image]

Comment: This is probably the best solution, I don't get the downvote. Maybe you should take the material ui breakpoints but other the that this is great!

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for something that behaves like bootstrap's `.container` then I would use Material UIs `<Container />` tag. As a starting wrapper/container, I would not use the `<Grid />` tag.

```
<Container maxWidth="lg">
  <!-- Content here -->
</Container>
```

https://material-ui.com/components/container/

Answer (score 1):

Building on OP's comment on OP's post, you can make a specific component that is meant to create a bootstrap style container:

```
import React from "react";
import { Grid } from "@material-ui/core";

const BootstrapContainerGrid = props => {
  return (
    <Grid container style={{ marginTop: "3em" }}>
      <Grid item lg={2} md={2} sm={1} xs={false} />
      <Grid item lg={8} md={8} sm={10} xs={12}>
        {props.children}
      </Grid>
      <Grid item lg={2} md={2} sm={1} xs={false} />
    </Grid>
  );
};
export default BootstrapContainerGrid;
```

Then pass in your actual component as a child to this bootstrap style container:

```
<BootstrapContainerGrid>
  <MyComponent>
    ...
  </MyComponent>
</BootstrapContainerGrid>
```

Now at least you have reusability and make it easy to edit how your "container" appears.

UPDATE [5/26/19]: Material-ui v4 has a Container component in core "@material-ui/core/Container" which seems to act like a bootstrap container.
https://material-ui.com/api/container/